# Create zip tables in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, impala, hadoop-partitioning

I have tried to create table whic is not zip like this.

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (|   a BIGINT,    b BIGINT,    v STRING,   d TINYINT   )  STORED AS TEXTFILE  LOCATION /path/to/directory/
```

It's not zip table. I want to also create new table with zip to take history of this table. How can i create just 1 table with zip ?

Comment: `STORED AS TEXTFILE` isn't compressed, no. Why didn't you use a different storage format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set below properties

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
```

Now insert data into backup table

```
INSERT INTO backup_table select * from example_table
```

Now data will convert into Gzip format

Comment: so after that all tables will be zip  ? should i write it always before insert any table ?

Comment: all data files will be compressed in gz , you need to set these properties once per session , if you exit the session and again start new session set them again before insert data into backup table

Comment: last question is should i insert data in hive or also can insert via impala ? and could you add a link below your answer about that question.thanks for reply

Comment: yes you can insert data via impala also , i didn't get the last part of your comment

Comment: but session was opened on hive ? how can hdfs knows it ?

Comment: if you are using hive CLI, till the time you dont exit session remain open , once you exit session will close, if you are executing query using some script, till the time script is executing session remain open